# Switch on sender for shared LostFocus event handler

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

I have a form with seven textboxes, all describing different attributes of a used car. In the shared `LostFocus` event of my textboxes, I need a case statement which determines the particular `TextBox` that lost focus. I then need to perform different various tasks, but I don't think they matter to my question.

How can I tell which textbox lost focus in my shared `LostFocus` event handler?

```
Select Case ________???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of two things.

The first is to select on the name

```
Dim tb as TextBox = CType(sender,TextBox)

Select Case tb.Name
    Case "TextBox1"
```

The second is what I prefer to do, it is to use the Tag property of the TextBox and put an unique number in it. So in that case your Select statement would look like.

```
Dim tb as TextBox = CType(sender,Textbox)

Select Case CInt(tb.tag)
    Case 1

    Case 2
    ....
```

The other thing that you mentioned was how to make sure of which TextBox lost its focus. There is a [LostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx) Event you can Handle also in addition to the Leave event you are handling now.

Comment: Appreciate it, thank you. Our assignment is clear in that we have to do this in the _Leave event:

SHARED TEXTBOX LEAVE
 Create a shared event procedure which will validate all TextBoxes when the user tabs or clicks out of the control (Leave event)
o Declare a generic TextBox which will represent the TextBox that triggered the event
o Use a case statement to determine which TextBox lost focus

Comment: @PhillCookie Ok, I just through the last in as a FYI. The Select Statements should work for you. The sender object will be the Textbox that just lost its focus.

Comment: Really appreciate you taking the time to explain....Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @PhillCookie No problem, let me know if you run into issues

Answer (score 2):

That would be `Select Case DirectCast(sender, TextBox)`.